# How to solve two layers Async Call in AWS Step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

There is a use case in AWS Step function

SFN = Step Function; Lambda = Lambda Function; BE = Backend API

1. SFN => Lambda => BE
2. BE ==requestId==> Lambda ==requestId==> SFN
3. BE continues the task , and when it completes, resumes SFN flow.

This is what i am supposed to do

1. My State Machine uses an async Task. Step Function service generates a task token to be used to identify the requested work and sends the token to the Lambda integration.
2. The Lambda function invokes your backend API, which begins its work and responds with the ID for the request.
3. The Lambda function completes. Lambda integration is configured with .waitForTaskToken task type, then the state machine execution will pause.
4. When backend API completes the work, it calls a SendTaskSuccess or SendTaskFailure API call passing the token with it. This will finalize the job that was associated with the token.
5. Once the Step Function service receives the API call to finalize the task associated with the token, the state machine execution will resume.

But the issue that i have here is I do not want to touch the back end API because that is not my control .

**Question is how we can achieve this Async call without modifying Back End API ?**